# Contar filas de una consulta en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

trato de contar las filas de una consulta ya realizada sin embargo no me regresa el resultado que deseo.
Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT DES_BOL, SKU_BOL, SUM(CAN_BOL) AS TOTAL
from TB_BOLSAS where DES_BOL ='908' and STS_BOL='AGREGADO'
GROUP BY DES_BOL, SKU_BOL;`
```

La cual me regresa el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me gustaria saber cuantas filas tiene ese consulta que ya realice. Trate de hacer algo como esto:

```
select DES_BOL, SKU_BOL, COUNT (SKU_BOL) AS REG_TOTAL
from tb_bolsas where DES_BOL ='908' and STS_BOL='AGREGADO'
GROUP BY DES_BOL, SKU_BOL;
```

Pero obtengo este resultado sin exito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: si en la segunda consulta solo quieres el numero de filas total quitale la linea del group by

Comment: Gracias si funciono.